# Flutter child to parent callback

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a simple ListView.Builder in a parent class `ParentRandomRender`

```
Expanded(
  child: Container( 
    child: ListView.builder(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
      itemCount: _data.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          print("do something");
        },
        child: Container(
          width: 44.0,
          height: 44.0,
          child: Align(
            child: new Image.asset(
              'images/save.png',
              width: 24.0, 
              height: 24.0
            ),
          )
        )
      },
    )
  )
)
```

The onTap works fine, it does what I want in `ParentRandomRender`.

Now I want my code to be cleaner so I create a `ChildRandomRow` class and put the `GestureDetector` in there like below.

```
class `ChildRandomRow` extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        print("do something");
      },
      child: Container(
        width: 44.0,
        height: 44.0,
        child: Align(
          child: new Image.asset(
            'images/save.png',
            width: 24.0, 
            height: 24.0
          ),
        )
      )
    )
  }
}
```

Now in the `ParentRandomRender` I do the following

```
Expanded(
  child: Container( 
    child: ListView.builder(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
      itemCount: _data.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return ChildRandomRow(); // on tap callback?
        )
      },
    )
  )
),
```

How can I capture or pass back the onTap callback from the `ChildRandomRow` into its `ParentRandomRender` class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pass a function to `ChildRandomRow`. Then, you can call it in `onTap`.

```
class ChildRandomRow extends StatelessWidget {
  final Function callback;

  const ChildRandomRow({this.callback}); //making it a named parameter, not required, but easier

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      // 1st option
      onTap: () {
        print("do something");
        callback();
      },
      // 2nd option
      onTap: callback, // if this doesn't work, try anonymous function aka () => callback(),
      ...
    )
  }
}
```

## How to use it

Here's how to implement the callback in your code.

```
Expanded(
  child: Container( 
    child: ListView.builder(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
      itemCount: _data.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return ChildRandomRow(
          callback: () {
            print("callback");
          },
        );
      },
    )
  )
),
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach can be, declare an `abstract class` for callback like this,

```
abstract class MyCallback {
  void onPositive(String data);
  void onNegative();
}
```

then inside `ChildRandomRow` declare this `MyCallback`,

```
class ChildRandomRow extends StatelessWidget {
  MyCallback mMyCallback;

  ChildRandomRow([this.mMyCallback]);
....
//do this inside onTap()
       onTap: () {
          mMyCallback.onPositive('YOUR DATA');
         },
```

Now on `ParentRandomRender` implement this `MyCallback`,

```
class _ParentRandomRender extends State<ContactUs> implements MyCallback {

  @override
  void onNegative() {}

  @override
  void onPositive(String data) {
// DO YOU LOGIC
  }
```

Pass `this` to provide `context` to `ChildRandomRow`

```
itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return ChildRandomRow(this); // on tap callback?
        )
      },
```